I am using Django for experiments on websites. There are different versions of Django. Which version is most suitable?
Which version of Django can be implemented as different texts have implemented different versions.
I tried each type of version of Django but could not succeed fully in implementing a small project "Hello,World" despite several tries.

Where's your code?

There are no different versions of Django, Django-5.0 is the successor of Django-4.2, and thus fixes a security vulnerabilities, makes the system more efficient, introduces new template tags, etc.

The problem came up as the text books and tutorials had mentioned that if a different version of Django other than what is used by them, then some results may or may not be successful.


There are different versions of Django. Which version is most suitable?

django-5.0 is the successor of django-4.2, and thus fixes a security vulnerabilities, makes the system more efficient, introduces new template tags, etc.
Using an old version thus makes not much sense. First of all, very old versions are not maintained anymore, so the pile of security vulnerabilities will keep growing. But these will eventually also not be in sync with new internet protocols, data formats, and architectural patterns.
The changes are often quite minimal, and documented in the release notes. Indeed, a major, compatibility breaking change in django-2.0 was that url(…) was removed [Django-doc]. This is documented in the release notes. If you thus have a tutorial that uses django-1.11, then you will have to go through all release notes up to django-5.0 and make the corresponding changes to modernize the application.
Therefore you better use a manual that is up-to-date with the latest version, since eventually you will have to update your project, just to keep it compliant with new protocols, architectural patterns and standards.

Thanks. That settles the issue raised by me. thanks a lot.
